# Check List1 contain all item in list2 with same list1 order in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

for example i have below array

```
Array1 = ["d","c","b"]
Array2= ["d","c","x"]
Array3= ["a","C"]
Array4= ["a","d","c","b","x"]
```

I want to compare Array1,2,3 to Array4 and the result should be Array1 because in contains d,c,b with right arrange in Array4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way to do it is to transform your array as a string, and then performs a `CONTAINS` where clause :

This is an example :

```
WITH ["d","c","b"] AS test, ["a","d","c","b","x"] AS array
WITH test, reduce(v='|', x in test | v + x + '|') as testAsString, reduce(v='|', x in array | v + x + '|') as arrayAsString
 WHERE arrayAsString CONTAINS testAsString
 RETURN test
```

Note that if in your array values you have a `|` this code can give you some false positive.

Comment: thanks that what i want, now do you know any way to get the repeat time of `test` in `array` in this example the repeat time is 1 but in `["a","d","c","b","x","d","c","b"]` this array the repeat time is 2.

Comment: You can make a replace of testAsString by an `@`for example, and then split on this character and take the length of the array minus one.